# multiplyByConstant method and matrices

Tags: matrix

```
public class Matrix{
    public double myArray[][];
    public Matrix(double a[][]){
        this.myArray=a;
    }


    public Matrix(int b,Vector...vectors) {

    double myArray[][] = new double[vectors.length][];
    int row = vectors.length;

    int column = vectors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        myArray[i] = new double[column];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

            if(b==0)
            {

                myArray[i][j] = vectors[i].getYourArray()[j];
            }
            else
            {
                myArray[j][i] = vectors[i].getYourArray()[j]; 
        }
    }
}
}
   public Matrix(int a){
       double [][] t=new double[a][a];
       Matrix z=new Matrix(t);
       for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<a;j++){
               if(i==j) z.myArray[i][j]=1;
               else z.myArray[i][j]=0;

           }
       }
       this.myArray=z.myArray;
   }

   public Matrix multiplyByConstant(double m){ // here


       }

   }
```

multiplyByConstatnt: Multiplication by a constant: taking a double as  a multiplication factor and  multiply every element of the matrix with that factor and return a new matrix.

I have also vector and test class,but i don't know how to use this method with matrix

Comment: Develop the java program for the following linear algebra problems 
Marix class. 
Develop a Matrix class holding a matrix as a two dimensional array of doubles. 
Include additional variables or parameters as required.

Comment: This is my main question and i have 3 classes;matrix,vector,test

Comment: 2 vectors come together and create matrix,2 x 2 ,3 x 2,2x3 it depends.And one of the method is here called "multiplybyConstant",it says Matrix times a constant

Comment: Yes i can imagine,i have to take matrix 2d dimension array,for loop and constant but how can i get here? i cannot write it